# android back botton make the application exist on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have `Welcome` activity, If the user press a button, a `Signin` activity is appear, when I am on emulator and press back, it goes from `signin` activity to `welcome` activity, but when i am on realy device and press back, the program is existed, why please ?

i will give you what functions i have on `signin` activity

```
public class Signin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    android.content.SharedPreferences someData;

    // Views
    EditText et_username, et_password;
    Button b_signin;
    Spinner s_type;
    TextView tv_usernameError, tv_passwordError, tv_signup, tv_forgetPassword;
    //
String username, password, IP, filename = "mySharedString";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState    ){}
private String getIP(){}
private void initialize(){}
public void onClick(View v){}
```

#### edit

on my `welcome` activity I have this function because i want to stop the music when the user press any button

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: You should provide a welcome activity code where you start the Signin activity. I suspect you finish() it out there.

Comment: @Fernado Margin are you overriding onBackPreseed method from SignIn activity?

Comment: yes i have a onpauase fucntion because on welcome i have a mucis and i want to stop the music when the user press any button , i edit the question

Comment: @PratikSharma no i don't

Comment: I edit the quesiton , when my function on welcome activity,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `finish()` in your `onPause()` will cause you activity to end.  I cannot explain why it is working in the emulator, but remove the call to `finish()` from `onPause`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling Finish() in onPause(), your Welcome Activity will be finished/Killed.

If you wish to have activities stacked, Please make sure you never kill the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

hmm... maybe you can use the onCreat method in the main activity to start the sing in activity and from the onCreat method of sing in activity you can start the welcome activity this way when the user click the back button when he is in the welcome activity he will get back to the sign in activity.